# How do I flip an Image in Preview?

Tags: macos, photos, preview.app

Is there a way to see the mirror image of a photo in Preview on OS X? Is there a way to have Photo Booth Photos not come out in a mirror image?

Comment: Command + L twice, or Command + r twice

Comment: No, that's turning it by 180 degrees. The OP wants to flip it so that it's mirrored. @jessh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. In Photo Booth, press ⇧⌘F, or go to *Edit » Auto Flip New Photos* to automatically flip them.

[image]

In Preview, just go to *Tools » Flip Horizontal*.